# псевдослучайный генератор чисел php

Tags: php, алгоритм

Нужен псевдослучайный генератор на php, который на вход принимает 1 параметр (строку), а на выходе выдаёт число внутри диапазона, например, от 1 до 1000 (диапазон планирую делать задаваемым 2-м и 3-м параметрами, но пока пусть будет так)
Для каждой строки результирующее число должно быть всегда одинаковым при множественных запусках.

Например,
`func_gen('qwerty')` пускай выдаст *367*, при повторном запуске `func_gen('qwerty')` результат должен остаться такой же.

Comment: Считаете CRC32 от строки, вызываете srand(), передав ему параметром CRC, потом дергаете rand() и получаете ровно то, что вам нужно. CRC32 можно заменить хэш-функциями, если их результат преобразовывать в число.

Comment: Спасибо большое!